# Hide 0 valued stack bar in stacked bar chart of JQPlot

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I am generating stacked bar chart using JQPlot where few stacks could have O values. my requirement is that I don't want to show O level of that stat which value is 0. please let me know what JQPLOT API I should use for that

My Code :

```
function getChart2()
    {
        var s1 = [32.40, 80.00, 80.00, 16.94, 72.12, 78.10, 80.00];
        var s2 = [0.00, 12.34, 3.68, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 15.67];

        var ticks = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E','F','G'];
  plot3 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', [s1, s2], {
    // Tell the plot to stack the bars.
    stackSeries: true,
    captureRightClick: true,
    seriesDefaults:{
      renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
      rendererOptions: {
          fillToZero: true, barDirection: 'horizontal'
      },
      pointLabels: {show: true}
    },
    axes: {
      xaxis: {
           pad: 1.05,
           tickOptions: {formatString: '%.2f %'},
           formatter:function() {if(this.x > 0.00) {
      return this.x;
    } }
      },
      yaxis: {
         renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
         ticks: ticks
      }
    },
    legend: {
      show: true,
      location: 'e',
      placement: 'outside'
    }     
  });
    }
```

[image]

Comment: And a live [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I used hideZeros:true option for this  and it is working now.

pointLabels: {show: true,hideZeros:true,labelsFromSeries:true,xpadding: 6}

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys thanks for helping me
I managed to solve my problem

i used it for to solve my problem:

stackSeries: true,
    captureRightClick: true,
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
            highlightMouseDown: true,
            barWidth: 40,
        },

```
    pointLabels: {
        show: true,
        formatString: '%s',
        formatter: function val(x, y) {

            //my Solution
            if (y != 0)

                return y.toString().toHHMMSS();
        },
    },

},
```